# local html page ajax response json structure

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm sending an ajax request to HTTP server which responds with JSON using PHP function json_encode($response), something like "{"OUT":{"XXX":"AAA"}" is send, the call is made from HTML page with pure JavaScript and the response is stored in the variable text:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var text = this.responseText;
   }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "http://server.com/prog.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send();
```

Everything works fine when the HTML page with JavaScript is stored on the server, the variable text becomes the JSON send by server as response: "{"OUT":{"XXX":"AAA"}"

If the HTML page is stored localy (file://) the variable text becomes only value: AAA

I'm aware of the Same-Origin-Policy and I'm testing from Chrome v. 61 with settings: 
 `--allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\tmp"`

It seems that the server is called and response is come, but it is somehow different filtered / formated / shrinked / structure lost when called from local page.

Do you have any hints how to avoid it without of the installation of a local http server? Could it help to use jquery insteed of pure JS?
Cheers, Annie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it was my trivial error at server side (PHP), so there is no difference between call from local and server stored html file. Case closed.